# Variables Baseform en C#

Tags: c#

No comprendo el funcionamiento de Baseform. Imagino es una forma base como lo dice el nombre pero no entiendo su funcionamiento. Lo tengo en el siguiente codigo y no entiendo su uso. Ya que en el codigo que reviso esta convirtiendo un objeto a Baseform. Pero no comprendo la razón

```
private void CargarDll(string sPantalla, string sDll, ref object myObj)
        {
BaseForm myNewForm;
 myNewForm = (BaseForm)myObj;
}
```

Comment: BaseForm es una clase... de algun tipo... habria que ver todo el codigo para entender que clase de que tipo es..

Comment: Puede que sea un class de la cual hereden funcionalidad los forms de la aplicacion, pero habria que analizar el contexto para entender